# How can you best offer a generic interface on bytestrings?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to offer a "user friendly" generic interface for a library I'm writing. It seems like the thing that ought to already exist, so I'd like to not reinvent the wheel.

At it's heart, the library is a wrapper over a lot of C functions that take `unsigned char[]`. Right now I'm using `vector` since it was easy to understand how to use `Mutable` to allocate and `freeze` C arrays being written by the library, but the more popular interface would be `ByteString`. Is there a good way to transparently convert them? And/or a good way to offer a generic interface for both of them?

As an example, I'd like to be able to write a function

```
doIt :: ByteArrayLike ba => ba -> ba
```

and have it operate on `ByteString` and `Vector Word8` identically.

Comment: Take a look at [`useAsCStringLen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.10.2.0/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v:useAsCStringLen) and friends, also the unsafe versions that don't copy. Maybe that is close enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of operations you want on `ByteString` and `Vector`, but you could take a look at the `lens` package, which provides generalized operations on both.

Perhaps implement a `IsByteString` instance for `Vector`? see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lens.html)